Error in libcrypto, Permission denied on Gitlab CI Actions SSH command
In gitlab ci/cd, I tried to deploy code to VPS using ssh key to connect but i met this error
Load key "/builds/socialmedia-askvolt/mynodejs-app.tmp/SSH_KEY": error in libcrypto
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
root@103.xx.xxx.xxx: Permission denied (publickey,password).

This is my command in .gitlab-ci.yml
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - chmod 400 $SSH_KEY
    - echo "$SSH_KEY"
  script:
    - ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i $SSH_KEY -p 24700 root@103.xx.xxx.xxx "
        docker login -u $REGISTRY_USER -p $REGISTRY_PASS &&
        docker ps -aq | xargs docker stop | xargs docker rm &&
        docker run -d -p 5000:5000 $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG"

Can you help to resolve this problem? Thanks for reading.
